# Does Snoke have a lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, snoke

I can not recall any scene in which you see Snoke use his lightsaber or even having it with him. So, what about his lightsaber? Doesn't he have a lightsaber?

The only thing that I found on the Internet is a rumor about a possible "black lightsaber", but nothing with a reference or true source.

Comment: Unclear from the source material we currently have but may be addressed in a later work of canon, I'm therefore voting to close this as off-topic as per our Future Works Policy

Comment: @edlothisd I disagree. "We don't know" is an acceptable answer if backed up, and it isn't like this question is specifically about episode 9 or anything.

Comment: @Edlothiad this isn't an off-topic question, i want one answer: "yes", "not", "we don't know"... If u know and have information about it answer my question. But i'm not make a question like "who is more strenght rey or kylo?" or "why the sky is blue?" for put this vote for close.

Comment: @Gawey Closing as per the FWP does not mean a question is bad or not. It merely is preserving the question for a later point in time. Otherwise answers now will say we don't know, then the future work comes out and the question is answered. But I'm just one man, the community has clearly decided to keep the question open.

Comment: @Edlothiad "Closing doesn't mean the question is bad. It just means that it can not be answered as-is. (where as is usually applies to question text, but COULD also apply to the question's ecosystem)." But we can answer it. The correct answer should be, "we do not know, but we never see him use one." This question is not about a 3 min trailer, and with snoke gone, we don't even know if they will bother addresing it.

Comment: @Edlothiad There's no guarantee that a later work of canon will address it, and there is supplemental material currently in existence that might already do so. This does not fall under our future works policy.

Comment: Understood, I will review the policy and be more careful next time, vote retracted.

Comment: Last time I've seen him he had one, to be precise in his belly: http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/File:Snoke_Death.png

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**We don't know**. He doesn't seem to have his own lightsaber in either of the films in which he appears. The film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) strongly implies that, at least in his latter days, fighting physical combat really isn't his thing.

> Supreme leader Snoke's first line of defence is his reclusiveness. 
>   His reputation looms large over first Order territories, but he rarely
>   makes  public appearances, preferring instead to transmit his image
>   across light years as a hologram. Very few ever see him in the flesh,
>   and those that are afforded an audience with the Supreme Leader are
>   kept within lethal distance of his ever-vigilant Praetorians. Snoke's
>   Force abilities are strong, but his body is broken, his stride
>   staggered and his muscles weak. He relies instead on the combat
>   prowess of his crimson protectors.

That being said, he does briefly possess Anakin's (Luke's) lightsaber, but only for a few moments.

Comment: Lack of knowledge on my part: given Yoda's saltos and jumps and so on, aren't strong Force abilities supposed to make up for one's physical weaknesses?

Comment: He probably spent his days smoking in his smoking jacket

Comment: @ClementC. They can, but "supposed to" is a bit much. We see Yoda move around just fine, although his advanced age hobbles him to the point where he uses a cane. We don't know the extent of Snoke's infirmity; it may well be severe enough that it makes no sense to use the Force to prop up his dueling skills (as opposed to just throwing people around with it or manipulating them mentally, which he seemed to do just fine). He could have conceivably just waved lightsabers around telekinetically, had he been inclined to their use at all.

Comment: @Machavity or his Snoking jacket

Comment: Also, lightsabers are generally identified as a weapon of the Jedi order, which Snoke particularly dislikes. Jedi (and Sith) normally make their own, per many EU works, though presumably there's nothing stopping Snoke from appropriating lightsabers just as General Grievous did. Nothing but the size of his hands...

Comment: @Orgmo Well played...

Answer (score 10):

TLJ represents the most screen-time we get of Snoke in the flesh, and we never see him with one (of course, we never "made it" to his boudoir either). But the better argument is that Snoke probably didn't have one on him because he didn't need one

1. He uses the Force to toss Rey around like a rag doll. Granted she's a nascent Jedi at this point, but still, Snoke clearly had a pretty powerful grasp on the Force, since he also tosses Hux about the same way, but over holo-communications
2. Snoke is surrounded by some pretty impressive imperial guards, well trained in defending against lightsabers (enough to give Rey and Kylo Ren a run for their money). It's close enough that, had Rey been alone, she probably would have been overwhelmed

Comment: Also, he can use force lightning (as seen momentarily in TLJ). Like the Emperor, that's probably enough of a weapon to defend himself with if he needs to.

Comment: More importantly, [he'd have gotten into BIG trouble with the Sith's union](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw7AYJikDJE&feature=youtu.be&t=1m9s).

Answer (score 9):

This isn't a conclusive proof of anything; but it's plausible circumstantial evidence:

In all the events of Episodes IV-VI, **Darth Sidious** (aka Emperor Palpatine) was never shown even a hint of having a laser sword. Even when facing Luke in ROTJ, he relied on Vader's obedience to use his own lightsaber, or the Far-more-powerful-than-mere-Jedi-swordplay Sith Lighting (which was a typical Sith approach, by the way - see Count Dooku's initial attempt against Master Yoda; as well as Snoke himself in E8).

Yet, we know for sure from Episode III, that Sidious had a lightsaber and was kinda sorta "killed 3 Jedi Masters in a couple of seconds and went toe to toe with Vaapad Master Windu" good with it.

In short, just because Snoke, the leader of First Order, isn't ever shown to wield a lightsaber (but only Force based assaults), based on prior examples it clearly does NOT guarantee he doesn't have one stashed someplace, just for light excercise.